# I have been trying to implement pagination in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

The below code is for pagination in HTML:

```
<button ng-disabled="" ng-click="previousPage(limit,offset)">
    Previous
</button>&nbsp;
<button ng-disabled="" ng-click="nextPage(limit,offset)">
    Next
</button>
```

In controller file:

```
$scope.previousPage=function(limit,offset){                 
adminservice.getPagination().then(function(response){
 adminservice.showAllVehicleDetails().then(function(){
   $scope.vehicledetails=response.data[0][limit-10][offset+10];
  console.log('limitNumber',limit)
  console.log('offsetNumber',offset)
        });
    });
 }
$scope.nextPage=function(limit,offset){
    adminservice.getPagination().then(function(response){
        adminservice.showAllVehicleDetails().then(function(){
                $scope.vehicledetails=response.data[0][limit+10][offset-10];
                });
        });
    }
```

In service file:

```
var getPagination=function(){
 return $http({
        url:apiurl+'paginatedetails',
        method:"GET",
        params:{limitNumber:limit,offsetNumber:offset}
    });
}
```

Can anyone show me the correct way to do it? When I'm running this code, the console shows error like: `limit is not defined  at Object.getPagination`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller file, you have to pass limit,offset to `adminservice.getPagination(limit,offset)`

```
$scope.previousPage=function(limit,offset){                 
adminservice.getPagination(limit,offset).then(function(response){
 adminservice.showAllVehicleDetails().then(function(){
   $scope.vehicledetails=response.data[0][limit-10][offset+10];
  console.log('limitNumber',limit)
  console.log('offsetNumber',offset)
        });
    });
 }
$scope.nextPage=function(limit,offset){
    adminservice.getPagination(limit,offset).then(function(response){
        adminservice.showAllVehicleDetails().then(function(){
                $scope.vehicledetails=response.data[0][limit+10][offset-10];
                });
        });
    }
```

And in service file you have to also write like this

```
var getPagination=function(limit,offset){
 return $http({
        url:apiurl+'paginatedetails',
        method:"GET",
        params:{limitNumber:limit,offsetNumber:offset}
    });
}
```

I think this work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to pass the `limit` and `offset` back to service at each `click` call:

```
var getPagination=function(limit, offset){
 return $http({
        url:apiurl+'paginatedetails',
        method:"GET",
        params:{limitNumber:limit,offsetNumber:offset}
    });
}
```

Now in the click function pass the arguments:

```
adminservice.getPagination(limit, offset)....
```